# Multivariable regression matrix

Tags: statistics, regression

A table is given the data: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0nhF.png)

Based on this table, we computed

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i1}^2 = 471$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i2}^2 = 163.84$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i1}X_{i2} = 235$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i1}Y_i = 4915.3$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i2}Y_i = 3103.66$

We consider the following model involving both independent variables and an intercept: $$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{i1} + \beta_2X_{i2} + \epsilon_i$$

where $\beta_j, j = 0,1,2$ are $3$ parameters and $\epsilon_i$ are pairwise indepedent random errors with mean $0$ and common variance $\sigma^2$. In the matrix notation, the model is

$$Y = X \beta + \epsilon$$

$$ X=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 7 & 2.6\\
1 & 1 & 2.9\\
1 & 11 & 5.6\\
1 & 11 & 3.1\\
1 & 7 & 5.2\\
1 & 11 & 5.5\\
1 & 3 & 7.1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ Y=
\begin{bmatrix}
78.5 \\
74.3 \\
104.3 \\
87.6 \\
95.9 \\
109.2 \\
102.7 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

(a) how do I calculate XX?

Comment: Did they mean $X'X$ or something?

Comment: says $XX$ on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** It´s almost sure that it is a typo. The formula for the estimated parameters $\beta_0,  \beta_1$ and  $\beta_2$ is

$$ \hat{ \beta}  =\left(\textbf{X}^{'}\textbf X \right)^{-1}\textbf{X}^{'}\cdot \textbf Y$$

It can be seen that it is necessary to calculate $\textbf{X}^{'}\textbf X$ and $\textbf{X}^{'}\cdot \textbf Y$ to obtain $\hat{ \beta}$.